# Why does a reference to a temporary struct (`&Foo { … }`) live long enough, but a reference to a variable (`let foo = Foo { … }; &foo`) does not?

Tags: rust, borrow-checker

In the rust code below, I would expect both calls to `pass_through` to fail, since both `a` and `b` go out of scope at the end of the inner block. However, for some reason the following happens:

- Creating a reference to an `NC` value and and storing that reference in `a` allows it to live long enough.
- Creating an `NC` value and storing it in `b`, then taking a reference to `b` for the function parameter causes an error.

```rust
#[derive(Debug)]
struct NC(i32);

fn pass_through(x: &NC) -> &NC {
    x
}

fn main() {
    let a2: &NC;
    let b2: &NC;
    {
        let a = &NC(1);
        a2 = pass_through(a);  // Works fine

        let b = NC(2);
        b2 = pass_through(&b); // Error, borrowed value does not live long enough
    }
    println!("a2 - {:?}", a2);
    println!("b2 - {:?}", b2);
}
```

Why does the borrow checker treat these two cases differently?

Comment: I am guessing `&NC(1)` has `'static` lifetime (since the expression is evaluated at compile time and written into the program text), but `&b` has the lifetime of `b`.

Comment: And that's the problem if you have a language without specification. Don't get me wrong, I love Rust, but I think a formal specification should exist.

Comment: You don't need the `pass_through` function, `= a` and `= &b` work the same

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This works for the `let a` case because `&NC(1)` refers to a read-only static that is automatically created by the compiler.  The inferred type of `a` includes the lifetime.

```
// These two lines are equivalent:
let a = &NC(1);
let a: &'static NC = &NC(1);
```

The `'static` lifetime is valid for the entire program, so there won't ever *be* a lifetime error assigning a `'static` reference to something.  The line `a2 = pass_through(a);` works because the lifetime of `a2` is unrelated to the lifetime of `a`.  All this does is copy the reference stored in `a` into `a2`, therefore **`a2` does not depend on `a`'s lifetime at all.**  They are both `&NC` variables that refer to the same value.  I think this is what you were confused about.

The `b` case fails because the `b2` reference outlives the lifetime of `b`.

It's important to note that there is a hidden lifetime parameter in the signature of `fall_through`.  It's as though you wrote this:

```
fn pass_through<'a>(x: &'a NC) -> &'a NC {
```

This just means that the lifetime of the returned reference is the same as the lifetime of the input reference.  In the `pass_through(a)` call, the lifetime parameter `'a` becomes `'static`.  In the `pass_through(b)` call, the lifetime parameter `'a` matches the lifetime of `b`.  In other words, this function is a simple identity function -- it returns its argument exactly, both in terms of its value and its type/lifetime.

Comment: Thanks for this answer! Based on the other similar question linked above, It seems like `a` is given a static lifetime due to RFC-1414 (https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/blob/master/text/1414-rvalue_static_promotion.md), correct?

Comment: @Wilduck Correct, and so the type of `a2` is also inferred to be `&'static NC`.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps this is due to the way the compiler determines the lifetime of a reference.

In the case of the variable **a**, the compiler, analyzing the entire block, sees that the longest lifetime of the variable **a2**, which will be assigned a reference, extends its lifetime, because the variable does not own the data.

However, in the case of **b**, everything is different, the variable owns the data, which means that when you exit the block, the data will be deleted and the link will be valid.